# Finding elements with css selector == #linkreturned an unexpected error

Tags: protractor

I'm getting this error when running a file with protractor:

```
$ ./protractor config.js 
Using the selenium server at http://ie11.dev:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
F

Failures:

  1) test a simple mouseMove() it should show a popup
   Message:
     UnknownError: Finding elements with css selector == #linkreturned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 301 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'WIN-A0RAN2MRA9O', ip: '172.16.196.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:33476/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: d59ae082-5864-4734-9df1-5f0dff04bb7b
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: Finding elements with css selector == #linkreturned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 301 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'WIN-A0RAN2MRA9O', ip: '172.16.196.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:33476/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: d59ae082-5864-4734-9df1-5f0dff04bb7b
==== async task ====
WebDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#link"))
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/xxxxxxxxxxxx/protractortest/test.js:6:25)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/xxxxxxxxxxxx/protractortest/test.js:2:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxxxxxxxxxxx/protractortest/test.js:1:63)

Finished in 2.04 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] internet explorer11 #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

**test.js**

```
describe('test a simple mouseMove()', function() {
  it('it should show a popup', function() {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.driver.get('file:///C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/protractortest/index.html');
      browser.sleep(1000);
      expect($("#link").isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
      // expect(element(by.id("link")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
      // browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id("link"))).perform();
      // browser.sleep(5000);
      // expect($("#hover-div").isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**index.html**

http://pastie.org/private/mm4xedyqsw0vrpmm5gqwiw

Selenium: 2.44
Protractor: 1.7.0
VM with IE11 and Win7

The whole purpose of this test is to check if mouseMove() works under IE11. But I'm not being able to select an element.

By the way, IE11 works well in another project, so there's something in the configuration that I'm probably missing in this example. But the other project is too complex and it has a really big configuration.

Comment: One important difference with my current project is that in this example I'm not testing an angular app but a normal HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that I was using the file:// protocol. I changed to http:// (installing Apache, etc. on my host machine and accessing that from the VM) and it worked. I guess this was because some kind of security setting in IE 11. I'd wished a more descriptive error.